# Option to select style always defaults to last style option

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an option which allows the user to select a background color. However when the user selects an option it defaults  to Green. If I uninstall the app the backgound color defaults to green. If I remove the option green it defaults to the color above(Blue). I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
public class UserMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button preview;
Spinner spinnerColor;
SharedPreferences preferences;
public static String theme = "Blue";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         preferences = getSharedPreferences("StylePref", 0);
         theme = preferences.getString("THEME", "Red");
        if(theme.equals("Red"));
        {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Red);
        }
        if(theme.equals("Blue"));
        {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
        }
        if(theme.equals("Green"));
        {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Green);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_menu);
        System.out.println(theme);
        spinnerColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerColorMenu);
        preview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previewButton);
           preview.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v)


    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();
        String bgColor = spinnerColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
        preferencesEditor.putString("THEME", bgColor);
        preferencesEditor.commit();

        if(bgColor.equals("Red"))
         {
            //Intent intent = getIntent();
            //intent.putExtra("Theme", "Red");
          finish();
          //startActivity(intent);
         }
         else if(bgColor.equals("Blue"))
         {
             Intent intent = getIntent();
            //intent.putExtra("Theme", "Blue");
           finish();
           startActivity(intent);
         }

         else if(bgColor.equals("Green"))
         {
             Intent intent = getIntent();
            //intent.putExtra("Theme", "Green");
           finish();
           startActivity(intent);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(theme.equals("Green"));
```

remove semicolons at the end of if blocks.

Comment: Oh my god, Thank you. I cant believe I missed that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have some semi-colons out of place.

```
        if(theme.equals("Red")); <--- Remove this ;
        {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Red);
        }
        if(theme.equals("Blue")); <--- Remove this ;
        {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
        }
        if(theme.equals("Green")); <--- Remove this ;
        {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_Green);
        }
```